getting data out of .MB files for paradox Database
So I've been given this old Paradox database from the 90s that contains data we need for our project. So far with some tools I've found, I've been able to extract some of the data out but a lot of it seems to be in the memo format which means it's being stored in the .MB files.
So far I can't find a way to get the data out of the .MB files. Is there any way to do this?
I've used online converters and some python libraries with some being able to get some of the data out but not the data out of the .mb files

Have you tried opening it with paradox and see if it supports export formats that are easier to deal with?

this database was built on paradox 3. Newer version don't seem to be compatible with it

Can you guess my next suggestion?

I'm not to sure what else to try?

Open it with a Paradox version that's compatible with this file

That's the issue I need paradox 5 which I do not have a copy of and also don't have a machine running that old of an operating system

It took me under 10 seconds to find a copy, and this will run in DOS Box.
